# Keep the wordpress custom type, after disabling theme?

Tags: custom-post-types

I used a theme, which created a custom type.
Now I want to change the theme, but when I disable the theme, the custom type is also disabled. I tried using CPT plugin, and re-create the custom type, but it tells me that the custom type is already present and it can't recreate it.

I tried looking into the theme's function.php to copy the codes to my new child theme, but in the code it is refering to a lot of variables which I don't understand.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new folder in the plugins folder, called something like 'custom-taxonomy'. Create a file with the name 'custom-taxonomy.php' and paste the code below in it. The words 'Image' and 'Images' should be replaced with the name of the custom taxonomy of your current theme.

Don't forget to activate the plugin. Also, it could be that you'll need to change the true/false values for things like 'public' and 'has_archive'.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Post Type
 * Plugin URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/my-first-plugin
 * Description: The very first plugin that I have ever created.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Your Name
 * Author URI: http://www.mywebsite.com
 */    

function custom_post_type() {
        $post_names = array(
            'slug' => 'image',
            'singular' => __( 'Image', 'plugin-name' ),
            'plural'   => __( 'Images', 'plugin-name' )
        );

        register_post_type( strtolower($post_names['slug']),
            array(
                'labels'             => array(
                    'name'               => $post_names['plural'],
                    'singular_name'      => $post_names['singular'],
                    'add_new'            => sprintf( __( 'Add new %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['singular']) ),
                    'add_new_item'       => sprintf( __( 'Add new %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['singular']) ),
                    'edit'               => sprintf( __( 'Edit %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['singular']) ),
                    'edit_item'          => sprintf( __( 'Edit %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['singular'] )),
                    'new_item'           => sprintf( __( 'New %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['singular'] )),
                    'all_items'          => sprintf( __( 'All %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['plural'] )),
                    'view'               => sprintf( __( 'View %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['singular'] )),
                    'view_item'          => sprintf( __( 'View %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['singular'] )),
                    'search_items'       => sprintf( __( 'Search %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['plural'] )),
                    'not_found'          => sprintf( __( 'No %s found', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['plural']) ),
                    'not_found_in_trash' => sprintf( __( 'No %s found in trash', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['plural'] )),
                    'parent_item_colon'  => '' /* text for parent types */
                ),
                'description'           => sprintf(__( 'Create an %s', 'plugin-name' ), strtolower($post_names['singular'])),
                'public'                => true,
                'show_ui'               => true,
                'show_in_menu'          => true,
                'publicly_queryable'    => true,
                /* queries can be performed on the front end */
                'has_archive'           => true,
                'rewrite'               => array(),
                'menu_position'         => 5,
                'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
                'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
                'hierarchical'          => true,
                'query_var'             => true,
                'show_in_rest'          => true,
                /* Sets the query_var key for this post type. Default: true - set to $post_type */
                'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes'),
            )
        );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_types', 11 );
```

Comment: You can see the post-type properties with `echo get_post_type_object('image')` (replace 'image' with the post-type name). Put that code somewhere in a theme file like front-page.php and check out the properties of the custom post-type.

Comment: I did not design the theme. This is the first part of the code that registers the custom type:
    public function register_portfolio() {
        if ( function_exists("cloudfw_get_option") ) {
            $post_slug = sanitize_title( cloudfw_get_option( 'portfolio',  'slug', 'portfolio' ) );
            $category_slug = sanitize_title( cloudfw_get_option( 'portfolio',  'category_slug', 'portfolio-category' ) );
            $filter_slug = sanitize_title( cloudfw_get_option( 'portfolio',  'filter_slug', 'portfolio-filter' ) );

Comment: How can i paste the code here?!

Comment: OK, so the post-type is called 'portfolio'. If you take the code above and create a plugin, you should replace all occurences of 'image' and 'images' with portfolio and I thin you should be good to go. If you're missing abilities then you should check out the post-type properties as stated above.

Comment: Should I also change plugin-name to some name?

Comment: I really appreciate your help.
in this code from the previous theme, what should the second argument be?
nafis is the name of the theme.

        /** Category Labels */
        $portfolio_tag_labels = array(
            'singular_name'          => __('Related Tag', 'nafis-core'),

Comment: You don't really have to change the 'plugin-name', it's just for translation purposes.

Do you mean the second argument in `__('Related Tag', 'nafis-core')`? That's for translation purposes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unregister_post_type('slug')` - where 'slug' is the CPT, such as 'portfolio' or 'book' or whatever your particular CPT is, and then re-register the CPT. I would suggest doing this in your own custom plugin so you can change themes freely.

So if your CPT is 'portfolio' you can create a file in `/wp-content/plugins/wpse_360145_create_cpt/create-cpt.php`:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Create CPT */

// Run everything when the plugin is activated
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpse_360145_activation');
function wpse_360145_activation() {
    // First, unregister the post type
    // (be sure to set this to *your* CPT)
    unregister_post_type('portfolio');
    // Next, re-register it from scratch
    // (You may have to play around with the settings)
    register_post_type('portfolio',
        array(
            // Plural, human-readable label for menu
            'label' => 'Portfolio Pieces',
            // Show in REST API must be true for the Block Editor
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            // Enable Title, Editor, and Excerpt
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt'),
            // has_archive will create http://example.com/portfolio
            // much like a Post Category archive
            'has_archive' => 'portfolio'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

There are a number of other settings CPTs can have, so you may have to look up each parameter and adjust to make the CPT work exactly the way you want it to. See [register_post_type() in the Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/).

With this approach, you just activate the plugin to try the settings, and if anything needs tweaking, deactivate, make the changes, and reactivate, and the `unregister_post_type()` call will make sure the old attempt is completely cleared out.

Answer (score -1):

In your old theme copy all of the code that registers the post "type register_post_type()" etc into the functions.php of the new theme.